# Calling UnsubscribeAll() on a Redis ConnectionMultiplexer affecting other redis subscriptions

Tags: c#, redis, publish-subscribe, stackexchange.redis

I have a Redis Connection Multiplexer class which I inject into two of my classes in the constructors.

```
public class CLASS_1 {
    IConnectionMultiplexer _redis;
    public CLASS_1(IConnectionMultiplexer redis){
        _redis = redis
        subscribeToChannel()
    }

    public subscribeToChannel(){
         ISubscriber redisSubscriber = null;
         redisSubscriber = _redis.GetSubscriber();

         redisSubscriber.Subscribe("REDIS_CHANNEL",(channel, message) => {
             // alway listen to the messages and perform the task
         }
    }

    ~ CLASS_1(){
        redisSubscriber.Unsubscribe("REDIS_CHANNEL")
    }
}

public class CLASS_2 {
    IConnectionMultiplexer _redis;
    public CLASS_2(IConnectionMultiplexer redis){
        _redis = redis
    }

    public async executeCommand(){
         ISubscriber redisSubscriber = null;
         redisSubscriber = _redis.GetSubscriber();

         /// perform a task
         
         await redisSubscriber.SubscribeAsync("REDIS_CHANNEL", callBack);

         /// perform a task

         if (redisSubscriber != null) {                  
             redisSubscriber.UnsubscribeAll()
             // even if I do redisSubscriber.Unsubscribe("REDIS_CHANNEL") it still affects the other subscriptions                  
         }
    }

}
```

`CLASS_1` is a singleton class and I am subscribing to a Redis channel in `CLASS_1`. Which means it only subscribe to the channel once. This class is always listening to the channel messages and perform some tasks when any message is received. The only time `CLASS_1` unsubscribe to the channel is in the destructor.

Now, `CLASS_2` is not a singleton class and there are few instances of it around the app. `CLASS_2` also subscribes to the same channel subscribed in `CLASS_1`. But `CLASS_2` also does an Unsubscribe at some point while the program is running.

Now, the problem arises when the `CLASS_2` does an unsubscribe, it also unsubscribe the active subscription in the `CLASS_1` and I do not want to unsubscribe the subscription in `CLASS_1`.

Now I am trying to figure if using the ConnectionMultiplexer is causing the issue? Or any information would be helpful.

Thank you in Advance! :)